# How to fix a htaccess 301 redirect that contains a ? symbol

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

A new website has just gone live and there is a htaccess file which has 301 redirects in order to direct people from the old pages on the old domain to the new pages on the new domain.

However, because there is a ? and = symbol in the links it's not working.

I understand I'll need to take advantage of the query string, but I can't work out how to get these three examples working.

```
Redirect 301 /index.cfm?task=what_we_do http://domain.com/services/
Redirect 301 /pagecontent/_newsitem.cfm?newsid=63 http://domain.com/name-of-article/
Redirect 301 /pagecontent/_people.cfm?peopleid=3 http://domain.com/about-us/meet-the-team/john-smith/
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a query string in the redirect. you have to use mod_rewrite.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^task=what_we_do$
RewriteRule ^index.cfm http://domain.com/services/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_newsid=63$
RewriteRule ^pagecontent/_newsitem.cfm http://domain.com/name-of-article/? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_peopleid=3$
RewriteRule ^pagecontent/_people.cfm http://domain.com/about-us/meet-the-team/john-smith/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Brilliant. Read lots of similar things but they didn't help. This was spot on. Many, many thanks.

Comment: In fact, the people and news ones aren't working. The only difference is the _ symbol, is that causing an issue?

Comment: Or the = symbol

The error is it goes to: http://domain.compagecontent/_people.cfm?peopleid=3

Comment: What do you mean? It's missing a slash?

Comment: I managed to fix that. It's instead going to: http://domain.com/pagecontent/_people.cfm?peopleid=3 - So it's changing the domain part but nothing after that.